# How to return partial string in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Lets say I have a string `The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence.`  How could I specify that I want to keep only the characters that are before the `<br>` tag, stripping out the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use something similar, don't know if it's more efficient.

```
<cfset string = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence.">

<cfset firstPiece = listGetAt(string, 1, "<br>")>
<cfoutput>#firstPiece#</cfoutput>
```

I like it because I determine the output prior to output rather than on output. But orangepips is nice because you could tailor your output based on the context..

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments the above code indeed produces "The" because of the way CF treats each character as a delimiter.

But `<cfset firstPiece = listGetAt(string, 1, "<")` produces "The big brown fox jumped".

**From the CF Documentation**

> **Delimiters**
>
> A string or a variable that contains
> one. Character(s) that separate list
> elements. The default value is comma.
>
> If this parameter contains more than
> one character, ColdFusion processes
> each occurrence of each character as a
> delimiter.

Comment: No, CF treats the delimiters as separate characters. So the end result is just "The".

Comment: @nick - Just make sure "<" works in your scenario. If it is possible your substring contains "<" or other html tags besides `<br>`, you should use something else. If you prefer not to use regular expressions, a combination of findNoCase and left/mid should work too.

Comment: @nick, Leigh is right. Make sure this works for you in the long run because if you `<cfset firstPiece = listGetAt(string, 2, "<")` it will return `br> over the fence.` which I'm pretty sure you don't want.

Comment: @nick, I had a very similar issue with html codes and my solution to this was `<cfset firstPiece = listGetAt(REReplace(string, "<br>", "|"), 1, "|")>`.  This will take whatever string you need to find can convert it into a single character that is most likely not in your string. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind dropping down to a bit of the old java underlying CF... AColdFusion string is actually a java string. Java's split uses a regex, which at it's simplest can just be the string you want to split on. So unlike [listToArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html) (which was extended in cf9 to allow multi-character splits, by the way), it is by definition multi-character. And since it's a regex, if you want it case insensitive, that too can be easily accomplished.

So given your string:

```
<cfset variables.myString = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence." />
<cfset variables.myStringArray = variables.myString.split("(<[bB][Rr]>)",2) />
<cfset variables.myString = variables.myStringArray[1] />
```

variables.myStringArray will contain an array with at most 2 elements, the part before the first <br>, and the part after the first <br> (the second parameter to split, the 2, says to only split into 2 parts, at the most) occurrence, which will leave any <br>'s in the second part of your string intact.

Comment: Less ugly/verbose: `string.split('(?i)<br>',2)`

Answer (score 1):

Everyone loves regex 'cept me. So here's an approach using string functions instead:

```
<cfset str = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence.">
<!--- roughly the equivalent of str.split("<br>") --->
<cfset pieces = listToArray(str, "<br>")> 
<cfoutput>#pieces[1]#</cfoutput>
```

**Update**

Meh, don't have a CF server handy. Stupid `listToArray()`. Here's one that should work.

```
<cfset str = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence.">
<cfset pos = find(str, "<br>")>
<!--- probably off by one here, don't have CF server handy --->
<cfset piece = left(str, pos)>
```

**Update #2**

Have access to a CF server now. This works. Addresses all the comments:

```
<cfset str = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence.">
<cfset pos = findNoCase("<br>", str)>
<cfset piece = (pos ? left(str, pos - 1) : str)>
<cfoutput>#piece#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: No CF treats each character as a separately. So the produces just "The". Dump the array and it is split this way: The|ig|own fox jumped|ove|the fence.

Comment: As Leigh mentions above, `findnocase` is probably better to use than `find`. (You'd also need a `cfif` block to handle cases where the tag or string or whatever wasn't present in the larger string.)

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis: update #2 does `findNoCase()` and uses an ternary statement instead of `<cfif>`.

Comment: Looks good ... and people using CF 8 or earlier (with no ternary operators) can just break the ternary statement out info a `cfif` block.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regexs:

```
<cfset str = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence." />
<cfset firstPart =     REReplaceNoCase( str,  "<br>.*$", "") />
<cfoutput>#firstPart#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7a49.html

Answer (score -2):

Why not use the `listFirst` function as in:

```
<cfset str = "The big brown fox jumped<br> over the fence." />
<cfset firstPart = listfirst(str, "<br>") />
<cfoutput>#firstPart#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Read the comments for the other responses to see why list functions will not work.